# Pandas: Get the index of the first value greater than all subsequent values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following pandas DataFrame:

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 1 |

I want to get the index of the row in each column where the value of the column at that row is greater than all subsequent rows. So in this example, my desired output would be

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What happens when there are more than one? i.e. `A = [2,1,4,4]`

Comment: idx = 3, as for idx = 2, the desired condition (greater) does not hold

Comment: @MichaelHodel I do not such see a constraint or requirement by OP in their question about index. The question is retrieval of the index where that row (value) is greater than all subsequent. Based on their description and results it looks like a `np.argmax` solution to me.

Comment: @Simon `np.argmax` if applied without reversing row orders has the same "issue" as `pd.idxmax` in that it returns the *first* occurrence of the maximum value in case multiple are occurred. See my answer and comments of Daniel Weigel's answer

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I guess I would use:

```
df.idxmax()
```

Or to get it formatted to your desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.idxmax()).T
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired result if there exists a column with a non-unique maximum

Comment: @MichaelHodel I don't think the OP has expressed such a constraint

Comment: @PaulH it reads "greater than", not "at least as  big as"

Comment: @MichaelHodel I'm not sure. It feels like you're reading too much into that and we should wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @PaulH I don't think so. If OP meant what what they wrote, the case is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[::-1].idxmax(axis=0)
```

Explanation: indices of last maximum values, by first reversing the row order such that index of first (i.e. lowest) occurrence is used (documentation for `DataFrame.idxmax` says *index of first occurrence of maximum*). The following code produces the desired result (as a `pd.DataFrame`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[2, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 2], [3, 4, 1]],
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=['A', 'B', 'C']
)
pd.DataFrame(df[::-1].idxmax(axis=0)).T
```

"index of the first value greater than all subsequent rows" <-> "index of last occurrence of maximum value"